# CSS Buttons overlaying

Tags: html, css, button, menu

I made menu on my site but the buttons on mobile version are laying on each other like on picture.[image]

I used this site to generate them: http://css3buttongenerator.com/
Link on that site is: https://bydave.net/

Comment: We need to see your codes to find out where the issue is from.

Comment: Your menu list items need to be set to `display: inline-block` instead of `display:inline` Also, your `ul` still has the default `padding` on the left side which needs to be reset. Your question in its current state would be useless after you solve the issue on your site. Consider adding the relevant code here for future reference.

Comment: Check responsive design and set your style

Comment: Side note: don't `using namespace std;`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to I haz kode! It fixed it! I used `display: inline-block` instead `display:inline` in this:

```
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

to this:

```
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The navigation section has a smaller set height than the actual visual representation of the buttons. If you were to adjust the height of the navbar to properly fit the buttons, they should no-longer overlap when displayed on smaller screens.

By the looks of it, the site is not incorporating responsive design. This results in sites not adjusting to different sizes and thus mobile screens.

Code-generators are often flawed in one or more ways. I highly recommend writing the markup yourself so you have full control, or at least learn how to read/write html & css so it becomes easier to edit and fix things.